# Plotting Histogram in R from pipeline result

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, statistics, histogram

I am using R to plot a histogram

i used this function to get the sum of all numbers of the same category

```
pll <- medical %>%  group_by(numHospStays) %>% summarise(val=sum(numVisits))
```

The result is a list

[image]

I am trying to plot a histogram with the numHospStays column as my x-axis. And the val column as the density of each category in numHospStays.

Answer (score 2):

Would `ggplot(pll) + geom_col(aes(x=numHospStays, y=val))` work? This is a bar plot that functions very much like a historgram I think...

Answer (score 2):

You have a discrete value on the x axis, so this is technically a bar chart rather than a histogram. You can use either `geom_bar()` or `geom_col()` for this:

```r
medical %>%  
  group_by(numHospStays) %>% 
  summarise(val = sum(numVisits))
  ggplot(aes(x = numHospStays, y = val)) +
  geom_col(fill = "deepskyblue2", color = "black") +
  labs(x = "Number of hospital stays", y = "Count")
```

[image]

or, to emphasize the exponential fall off in number of admissions, try a log scale on the y axis, plus perhaps a fill scale for aesthetic value and a tweak to the overall look using `theme_bw`:

```r
medical %>%  
  group_by(numHospStays) %>% 
  summarise(val = sum(numVisits))
  ggplot(aes(x = numHospStays, y = val)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = numHospStays)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "forestgreen", high = "red", guide = guide_none()) +
  labs(x = "Number of hospital stays", y = "Count") +
  scale_y_log10() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Providing a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with your data will help us to answer your question.

With some assumptions with your data, you can create a density histogram without the `group_by` and `summarise` steps using the code below:

```
ggplot(data = medical) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = numHospStays, y = ..density..))
```